# Connect a processor board to Raspberry pi

Tags: pi-2

I was recently wondering if there is a way (hypothetically) to **connect** **a external processor board to raspberry pi (like a intel board, or a ARM Sitara TI Board),** since I would prefer to have the advantage of rpi's ecosystem of products while having some added power (for robotics).

EDIT: I am now thinking of using one of the ARM Sitara processor boards.

Comment: Well there's of course the [compute board](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/tag/compute-module/) for any other boards my guess would be that you'll have to figure that out yourself.

Comment: What is the end goal ? Do you want to network your devices ? Do you have a high-level overview what device will fulfil a certain task ? Do you expect a single  fully transparent , faster machine to evolve from this setup (which is not normally meant with "clustering") ?

Comment: Which Intel board? What have you tried so far and what didn't work? As it currently stands, your question is rather broad...

Comment: I am trying ARM Sitara boards, offered by TI: http://bit.ly/TISitara

Comment: Currently, this is purely hypothetical.

Comment: Run a webserver on the Pi and your other machines. Connect via Ethernet. Issue commands to other machines via WebAPI or Node.JS that do things you need it to do. Tadaaa. (Ethernet benefits in reduced latency ~1ms - WiFi is OK if you ok with 50~500ms latency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to prevent you from interfacing with external boards to add functionality to your project. The Pi has a multitude of GPIO pins that can be used to communicate with external processors (e.g. [an Arduino](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/program-your-arduino-with-raspberry-pi)), as well as wired ethernet and optional wireless interfaces such as WiFi or Bluetooth. All of these can be used to distribute tasks to external connected devices which may offer capabilities beyond the Pi's.

The Pi can also be [overclocked](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-turbo-mode-up-to-50-more-performance-for-free/) to some degree, which can offer performance improvements.

What *isn't* possible is slapping a magic board on top of the Pi which dramatically increases CPU speed or available RAM. There is no physically accessible interface by which these can be augmented.

Comment: What i'm thinking is having the Raspberry Pi distribute tasks to the TI ARM Sitara Board.

Comment: Sounds like you're buying a BeagleBone Black? The BeagleBone is more commonly considered an alternative to a Pi, rather than an addition to a Pi, but it's certainly possible to have the two boards working together. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

If your processor offers some sort of of interface (SPI, GPIO, USB, Ethernet, etc.), you should use that.

If your're talking about directly connecting a processor chip to the Pi, you're out of luck. There's no way to connect an external CPU in any computer (yet). I'm referring to the literal CPU.